# angular2-notifications with i18n translate

Tags: internationalization, angular5

I'm  using  https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-notifications this package to get notification it works fine but it works at ts file like;

```
saveUser(user){
      //some process then notification will work.
      this.notif.success(
      'Yeahhh successfull create notification',
      {
        timeOut: 3000,
        showProgressBar: true,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        clickToClose: true,
        maxLength: 50
      }
   )
}
```

works fine but I'm using translate (i18n) and want to give these parameters by the language.And the package says it has a html function but I tried and couldn't do that which is

[image: normally I use that translate syntax at my html files and works very well but I don't know how am I going to use it at my ts file with notification]

Thank you

I guess img can't be seen , it was the code of html

```
this.notif.html(`<p translate > {{ 'City' | translate }}  Success</p>`)
```

Comment: What library are you using for i18n? They probably provide an injectable service along with that `translate` pipe for these types of situations where you have to manually get the translation (`ngx-translate` has a service to use if you are using that).

Comment: Yes I'm using ngx-translate let me check thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TranslateService to get your translation values.

First import the service.

```
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';
```

Then inject and use it like so:

```
export class YourComponent {
  constructor(translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.get('CITY').subscribe((res: string) => {
      console.log(res);
      //=> 'Whatever your translation is for "city"'
    });
  }
}
```

Further documentation can be found [here](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core#4-use-the-service-the-pipe-or-the-directive).

Comment: Yeah!! Thats what I was looking for best Regards.